# How to pass multiple excludes for fileset in Ant as an input parameter?

Tags: dynamic, ant, fileset

I am using a `fileset` in Ant and I would like to have the things to exclude as an extracted property, like an array of strings(or just a comma-separated string). By doing this I can have a dynamic *excludelist*.

```
<!-- IN MY PROPERTY FILE -->

thingsToExclude = File1.java,File2.java,File3.java

<!-- IN MY BUILD.XML -->

<fileset dir="${somePath}" casesensitive="yes">
    <exclude name="File1.java"/>
    <exclude name="File2.java"/>
    <exclude name="File3.java"/>
</fileset>


<!-- WHAT I WOULD LIKE -->

<fileset dir="${somePath}" casesensitive="yes">
    <excludeList name="${thingsToExclude}"/>
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `excludesfile` attribute of [`fileset`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) and point to your property file, that should do the trick.

> `excludesfile`: the name of a file; each line of this file is taken to be an exclude pattern.

Of course, you can use regex pattern like `*.java` to exclude a set of files as well.